# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un subscribe fuera de su método en ANGULAR 11/TYPESCRIPT?

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo una propiedad que obtiene el valor después de hacer subscribe si esta en el mismo metodo, pero ya fuera solo tiene el mismo valor inicial

```
 public inmueblesEncontrados=[]

  constructor( public PasardatosService:PasardatosService) {}

  ngOnInit():void {  
this.PasardatosService.enviarDatos.subscribe(values=>{
      this.inmueblesEncontrados=values; //le asigno el valor de values a esa propiedad

console.log(this.inmueblesEncontrados) //aqui si obtiene y me muestra el valor de values
    })
    


console.log(this.inmueblesEncontrados); //aqui me muestra indefinido ya que no tiene el valor de values

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*En realidad lo que necesitas puede hacerse de 2 formas. Pero debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente.*

*Debes tener en cuenta que la forma de trabajar de angular no es secuencial, es decir si colocas en un metodo a ejecutar un proceso y abajo haces otra cosa. en la ejecución no va a esperar a que el primer proceso termine sinó que va a trabajar todo en paralelo. Hay casos muy puntuales en los que si respeta eso.*

*Para tu caso, el segundo console.log se va a ejecutar antes de que el servicio termine de ejecutar e inicialice la variable que deseas usar.*

***Para ese caso, puedes hacer lo siguiente:***

```js
// En tu service tendrías el siguiente metodo
miServicio() {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(response => response, error => error));
}

// En el componente donde deseas implementar tu servicio tendrías que tener en cuenta 2 cosas
// 1. Agregar el servicio en tu constructor del componente. Cosa que ya lo tienes.
constructor(servicio: ClaseServicio) {}

//2. Para ejecutarlo podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera.
async ejecucionServicio() {
  let respuesta;
  await this.servicio.miServicio().toPromise().then((response) => {
    respuesta = response;
  }).catch(e => console.error(e));
  return respuesta;
}
```

*Tenemos la siguiente función el cual contiene la ejecución de nuestro servicio. y realiza un return de la respuesta obtenida. Debes tener claro que al realizar el async y await la respuesta que obtendremos será de tipo **Promise < void >**. Para poder obtener el dato real tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:*

```js
ejecucionServicio().then(response => {
  this.APIKey = response['access_token']
  console.log(this.APIKey);
});
```

*La verdad, considero que mejor lo haces de la manera que lo tienes. solo en casos muy necesarios usalo con el **async** y **await**.*

*Entonces, las dos formas serían. Como lo has expresado en tu pregunta, y poner todo lo que necesitas en la respuesta del subscribe, la segunda opción sería con el async y await.*

*Espero te sirva.*

Comment: Por ejemplo, lo que intento hacer es que el valor de values pase a inmueblesEncontrados y ya en el html mostrar los valores pero no lo toma y no me muestra nada

Comment: Según lo que mencionas en tu pregunta, dices que dentro del subscribe si lo obtienes, pero fuera no. Como comenté en la respuesta es porque en el orden de ejecución se imprime primero el console.log que está al final y luego el que está dentro del subscribe.

Comment: Puedes dejarlo como lo tienes, pero a nivel de html deberás colocar un *ngif, esto con el fin de que muestre la información de dicho campo, cuando obtengas la información

Answer (score 0):

No puedes, el `subscribe` es un observable que se ejecuta hasta que es completado, te marca indefinido por que el `console.log` se ejecuta antes del `subscribe`. Te recomiendo usar un [`Resolve`](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) y obtener tus valores mediante [`ActivatedRouteSnapshot`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) esto con el fin de obtener la información que necesitas antes de cargar el componente.

Por ejemplo:

```
@Component({templateUrl:'./my-component.html'})
class MyComponent {
  inmueblesEncontrados : any[] = []
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.inmueblesEncontrados= route.snapshot.data.values;
  }
}
```

Genera un `Resolve` para pasar la información a `ActivatedRoute`.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private PasardatosService:PasardatosService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.PasardatosService.enviarDatos;
  }
}
```

Ahora implementa el `Resolve` en tu ruta donde utilizas el componete.

```
 {
        path: 'my-route',
        component: MyComponent ,
        resolve: {
          values: MyResolver 
        }
 }
```

**ALTERNATIVA**

También puedes guardar el observable como variable y utilizarla en el HTML mediante el pipe [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). El cual se suscribe automáticamente al observable.

```
 inmueblesEncontrados$: Observable<any[]>; 
 ngOnInit():void {  
     this.inmueblesEncontrados$ = this.PasardatosService.enviarDatos;
  }
```

```html
<pre>{{ inmueblesEncontrados$ | async}}</pre>
```

Comment: Por ejemplo, lo que intento hacer es que el valor de values pase a inmueblesEncontrados y ya en el html mostrar los valores pero no lo toma y no me muestra nada

Comment: @DEXcarlos Cualquiera de las respuestas que te han compartido resuelven tu problema, al menos que no estés formulando bien tu pregunta y tu duda sea otra. Te invito a que compartas el código de tu servicio `PasardatosService`,dado que por lo que dices parece mas un error.